# ListFragment: prevent race condition between getListView() and onDestroyView()

Tags: android, race-condition, android-listfragment

I have a `ListFragment` that I want to update regulary. The update process itselfs is quite complicated and could take some time. That's why I made a thread that executes a new update 5 seconds after the previous update has been done. Then I create a handler to update the list, while keeping track of the position in the list.

The problem is that by quickly sliding between fragments in my `ViewPager` I can force a race condition: `onDestroyView()` can be called before the handler calls `getListView()`, resulting in the following error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Content view not yet created

My question is: how can I prevent this race condition? Is there any way to check if the view is still there? Checking if the `updateThread` has been interrupted in the code below is unfortunately not enough.

```java
    public class MyFragment extends ListFragment {
        private Thread updateThread = null;

        public void startUpdate() {
            /* Kill old thread */
            if (updateThread != null) {
                updateThread.interrupt();
            }

            final Handler handler = new Handler();
            Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    while (true) {
                        // ... collect data in `adapter`

                        final ArrayAdapter<String[]> ada = adapter;

                        handler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                if (ada != null) {
                                    // restore view position
                                    int index = getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition(); // CRASH here
                                    View v = getListView().getChildAt(0);
                                    int top = (v == null) ? 0 : v.getTop();

                                    setListAdapter(ada);
                                    ada.notifyDataSetChanged();
                                    getListView().setSelectionFromTop(index, top);
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        //... sleep for some second
                    }
                }
            };

            updateThread = new Thread(r);

            updateThread.start(); // start updating
        }


        @Override
        public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
            super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);

            if (isVisibleToUser) {
                startUpdate();
            } else {
                if (updateThread != null) {
                    updateThread.interrupt();
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [isAdded](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#isAdded%28%29) to check if you fragment is attached to activity